# Docker django app running but cannot access the webpage

Tags: python, django, docker, port

I am trying to run two separate django apps using docker (building on a linux server). The first  application runs smoothly (using default ports) the second one apparently runs (it says starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:5000), I got no issues looking inside the portainer. Everything is running and no issue is there. When I try to connect to the page, it fails.

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  vrt:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./nuovoProgetto:/VehicleRammingTool
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py wait_for_db && 
      python3 manage.py migrate &&
      python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment: 
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
    context: .
    command: celery -A nuovoProgetto worker --pool=solo --loglevel=info
    volumes:
     - ./nuovoProgetto:/VehicleRammingTool
    environment: 
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    
    depends_on:
     - vrt
     - redis

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV http_proxy=http://++++++++++proxyhere
ENV https_proxy=http://+++++++++proxyhere
ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
    https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir /root/.conda \
    && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

RUN python --version
RUN conda install -c conda-forge django psycopg2 celery redis-py django-leaflet django-celery-        beat django-celery-results django-crispy-forms osmnx geopy geocoder pathos

RUN mkdir /VehicleRammingTool
COPY ./nuovoProgetto /VehicleRammingTool
WORKDIR /VehicleRammingTool
EXPOSE 5000
```

**EDIT**

I can cURL via command line the page using the proxy option, but still I can't get there via browser

Comment: What system are you running on

Comment: Can you please specify the OS you're running this compose file on? Maybe accessing it from `host.docker.internal:5000` works.

Comment: What do the logs show when you try to access something? `docker-compose logs --follow`

Comment: when inside the container, can you reach the proxy? also if you remove the http_proxy declaration, can you access the app from outside the container?

Comment: Thanks, when I try to follow the logs, connecting to the page where I should see the app, nothing happens. I mean it is just static and no more logs are printed.

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: On the other running app, I use the same proxy conf and it is running well. Here the things I changed are the ports. On the other app, which is configured almost the same, I used ports 5432:5432 and manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5432

Comment: I've also tried to use port 5432:5432 and 0.0.0.0:5432 on this app (stopping the other one which holds that port) and I can reach the site. Now how can I use the port say 5000?